# 'System.DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'Text'

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a value to **CurrentRent.Text** and **NextRent.Text** (both labels on my form and keep getting the following error messages:

```
Error   1   'System.DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'System.DateTime' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   2   'System.DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'System.DateTime' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

How can I resolve it? This is my code so far:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CurrentDate.Text = "Today's Date: " + DateTime.Now;

        DateTime CurrentRent;
        DateTime NextRent;
        DateTime today = DateTime.Now;

        if (today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
        {
            CurrentRent.Text = "Current Rent Date: " + today.AddDays(-7);
            NextRent.Text = "Next Rent Date: "+ today.AddDays(7);
        }

    }
```

Comment: No, they are not labels. You have defined them as DateTime variables.

Comment: `CurrentRent` and `NextRent` aren't labels according to your code, they're `DateTime` objects.  What are the names of your labels?

Comment: I think it tells you that... CurrentRent is a variable of the datetime type. My guess is you called your text box CurrentRent as well?

Comment: The names of the labels are also `CurrentRent` and `NextRent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared a local variable that "hides" your labels:

```
 DateTime CurrentRent;
```

Just comment that out:

```
 // Don't include this - it hides your label:
 // DateTime CurrentRent;
```

Since that is declared locally, you're trying to set the "Text" property of the *local CurrentRent variable*, not your label.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've renamed it - how would I assign the value to my labels then > http://pastebin.com/XchQmpdy

Comment: @methuselah Comment out that declaration, then just do: `CurrentRent.Text = "Current Rent Date: " + cRent.ToString();`

Comment: Oh great thanks - it works. Quick question when I do `CurrentRent.Text = "Current Rent Date: " + cRent.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy");` it seems to give me the wrong details i.e. 27/07/2013... any idea why this happens

Comment: @methuselah use `ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` - lower case "mm" is minutes, not months ;)

Answer (score 4):

Well, the error seems pretty clear to me.  You're trying to set the text of a `DateTime`.  `DateTime` doesn't have a `Text` property.  If you want to be setting the text of some label, then set the text of a label, rather than the text of a `DateTime`.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I'm pretty new to C#, how would I accomplish this?

Comment: rename the label something else for starters

Comment: @methuselah You use a variable representing a `Label`, instead of a variable representing a `DateTime`.  Presumably they are already being created by the designer; if not, you can define them yourself the same way you defined your `DateTime` variables.

Comment: Thanks. I've renamed it - how would I assign the value to my labels then > http://pastebin.com/XchQmpdy